# DataSet Pagination Class in C#

Tags: c#

I've been tasked with pagination of a dataset at my job and think I've been able to address the problem but need review of my class to see if it's up to snuff and if there are any suggestions as to how it should be handled. It's simple enough and the logic appears to work, but I need a hand.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class DataSetPagination
    {
        private DataSet dataSet;
        private DataRow row;
        private DataColumn column;

        private int pageSize;
        private int totalPages;
        private int rowCount;
        private int currentPage;
        private int nextPage;
        private int previousPage;
        private int index;

        public DataSetPagination()
        {

        }

        public DataSetPagination(DataSet dataSet)
        {
            this.dataSet = dataSet;
            this.rowCount = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        }

        public DataSetPagination(DataSet dataSet, int pageSize)
        {
            this.dataSet = dataSet;
            this.rowCount = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            this.pageSize = pageSize;
            this.totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)this.rowCount / (decimal)this.pageSize);
            this.currentPage = 0;
            this.nextPage = 0;
            this.previousPage = 0;
            this.index = 0;
        }

        private void next()
        {
            this.index++;
            this.currentPage = this.nextPage;
            if (this.index > this.totalPages)
            {
                this.index = this.totalPages;
            }
            this.nextPage = this.currentPage + this.pageSize;
            if (this.nextPage > rowCount)
            {
                this.nextPage = this.rowCount - this.currentPage;
            }
        }

        private void previous()
        {
            this.index--;
            if (this.index < 0)
            {
                this.index = 0;
            }
            this.previousPage = this.currentPage - this.pageSize;
            if (this.previousPage < 0)
            {
                this.previousPage = 0;
            }
            this.currentPage = this.previousPage;
            this.nextPage = this.currentPage;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A tip for providing code examples: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. You don't need all those `using`s for instance.

Comment: They're just there incidentally.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make your pagination logic much simpler: you're intermingling logic and data too much IMO.

Here I've written an example of how you could separate these a bit more:

```
 public class Page
{
    public Page(int number, int size)
    {
        this.Number = number;
        this.Size = size;
    }

    public int Number { get; }
    public int Size { get; }

    public static IEnumerable<Page> 
        Paginate(DataSet data, int pageSize)
    {
        // how to divide data per page?
        // there's no indication in your logic
        // for this

        int rows = data.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        int total = (int)Math.Ceiling(
            (decimal)rows / (decimal)pageSize);

        return Enumerable
            .Range(0, total)
            .Select(index => new Page(index, pageSize));
    }
}

public class Pagination
{
    int currentIndex = 0;

    public Pagination(IEnumerable<Page> pages)
    {
        this.Pages = pages;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Page> Pages { get; }

    public bool HasNext
        => this.Pages.Count() > currentIndex;

    public bool HasPrevious
       => 0 < currentIndex;

    public Page Next()
    {
        if (!HasNext)
            throw new InvalidProgramException();
        currentIndex++;
        return this.Pages.ToList()[currentIndex];
    }

    public Page Previous()
    {
        if (!HasPrevious)
            throw new InvalidProgramException();
        currentIndex--;
        return this.Pages.ToList()[currentIndex];
    }
}
```

I've extracted a `Page` class which makes enumerating over the pages (`Previous` and `Next`) much easier and you won't have to deal with the low level indexing logic with only `int`s like in your code.

You can now turn a `DataSet` into an `IEnumerable<Page>` from which you can create a `Pagination` object.

This still has lots of problems:

1. The actual data from the `DataSet` isn't saved per page; there was no indication in your code how to access the data itself. So the `Page` class would need a `property` for this which you would set in the `ctor` and you'd extract this from the `DataSet` in the `Paginate` method.
2. It throws exceptions (don't do this). But to get around this you'd have to introduction some kind of `Option` or `Maybe` type; these are usually associated with `functional programming`.
3. I haven't tested this.

Hope this helps.